# How to find the end coordinates of UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So I am dynamically adding UILabels to a view along a "timeline". What I would like to do is figure out how to put the starting coordinates of the next UILabel a couple of pixels past where the last one was. I'm having a hard time figuring out where the last one ended. I've looked at a few similar questions and I can't seem to grasp how to do it. Everything is taking place in a for loop so I can update the xcoordinate variable each loop, but I need to know how to get the label size. Anyone have any ideas? I tried this but it didn't seem to work:

```
UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(labelsXpoint, 
                                                        topLabelYpoint,
                                                        labelWidth,
                                                        20)];

    CGSize labelSize = [title.text sizeWithFont:title.font constrainedToSize:title.frame.size  
                             lineBreakMode:title.lineBreakMode];
labelsXpoint += labelSize.width;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would get the top right & bottom right coordinates of the title label:

```
CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(title.frame.origin.x + title.frame.size.width, title.frame.origin.y);
CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(title.frame.origin.x + title.frame.size.width, title.frame.origin.y + title.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set the frame after you alter labelsXpoint.  Something like:

```
UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]init];

CGSize labelSize = [title.text sizeWithFont:title.font constrainedToSize:title.frame.size lineBreakMode:title.lineBreakMode];
labelsXpoint += labelSize.width;

title.frame = CGRectMake(labelsXpoint, topLabelYpoint, labelWidth, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions: `CGRectGetMaxX` and `CGRectGetMaxY`:

```
CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(title.frame), title.frame.origin.y);
CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(title.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(title.frame));
```